@context variable in implicit child content
I made a simple list component that works with INotifyCollectionChanged:
@using System.Collections.Specialized
@typeparam TItem

@if (Items != null && ChildComponent != null)
{
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        @ChildComponent(item);
    }
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public IList<TItem>? Items { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TItem>? ChildComponent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(_previousItems, Items))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_previousItems is INotifyCollectionChanged previousNotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            previousNotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        if (Items is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            notifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        _previousItems = Items;
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private IList<TItem>? _previousItems;
}

When I use this component and explicitly define the child content, I can use @context to access the properties of each item:
<ListComponent Items="ViewModel.Items">
    <ChildComponent>
        <option>@context.Name</option>
    </ChildComponent>
</ListComponent>

However, when I try to define the child content implicitly, I get an error:
<ListComponent Items="ViewModel.Items">
    <option>@context.Name</option>
</ListComponent>

error CS0103: The name 'context' does not exist in the current context

Examples such as TemplateColumn (Source) from quickgrid seem to support it though, so I am unsure what I am doing wrong. How to I get access to the @context variable from implicit child content?

To implicitly use a renderfragment use the name ChildContent not ChildComponent.
